# Independence of $\bar X$ and $S$ when $X$ is normal

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

Suppose I have $X_i,...X_n$ be i.i.d. multivariate normal variables. Then the MLE estimate for the mean is

$\bar X = \frac 1 nX 1'$

and for the covariance

$S = \frac{1}{n-1}X'(I-\frac 1 n11')X $

How do I show that $\bar X$ and $S$ are independent?

My plan is to rewrite $S$ as

$S = \frac 1 {n}(X-11'X)'(X-11'X)$

Not sure where to go from there. I was hoping that I could show that both quantities were functions of a known independent quantity and so independent.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of multivariate normal RVs as here, independence follows from uncorrelatedness. 
$$
S=(1/(n-1))X^T(I-11^T/n)X=(1/(n-1))X^T(I-11^T/n)(I-11^T/n)X,
$$
and it is enough to show that $(I-11^TX/n)X$ is independent of $\bar{X}=11^TX/n$, as $S$ is a function of the former. But then $(I-11^T/n)$ and $11^T/n$ are projecting $X$ onto orthogonal subspaces.
$$
Cov((I-11^T/n)X,11^TX/n)=(I-11^T/n)Cov(X,X)11^T/n=0.
$$
Btw, that isn't the mle for the covariance, it's the U-statistic/unbiased estimator.

Comment: Fixed the MLE thing, thanks. Why do you say $\bar X = 11^TX/n $? $\bar X$ is a vector, your calculation returns a matrix.

Comment: @badmax I'm treating $X$ as a column vector (likewise for other vectors)